# How to get the equivalent of "version lockfiles" for Alpine's apk packages? (to easily lock down package versions)

Tags: alpine-linux

I'm using Alpine Linux 3.7 in a Docker container.
I'm performing some `apk` commands inside a Dockerfile.

I have successfully pinned my dependencies to a particular major version:

```bash
apk add --no-cache \
'openssl<2' \
'freeradius<4' \
'freeradius-mysql<4'
```

But the exact behaviour of this command is sensitive to *when* the `apk add` command is run (i.e. *when the Docker image is built*).

*At the time of writing*, these constraints resolve to:

```bash
apk add --no-cache \
'openssl=1.0.2m-r0' \
'freeradius=3.0.15-r3' \
'freeradius-mysql=3.0.15-r3'
```

**If I run `apk add 'dep<majver'` *next year*, probably I will get different results.**

- I don't want my dependencies to change version *without my knowing*.

  - Yes, not even *minor version*. I do not trust semver 100% to keep me safe from breaking changes / regressions, so changing minor version should be done *under supervision only*.
- I don't want to hand-write the exact version resolutions (`dep=ver`). `'dep<majver'` is preferred.

Package managers such as `npm` and `yarn` have a nice solution to this. Version lockfiles.

You'd have *two* documents under version control:

- One manually-created document to express `'dep<majver'`
- One version lockfile, expressing (for each dependency) a specific `dep=ver` resolution which fulfils all your constraints.

  - This would be machine-generated. You would regenerate it *deliberately*, only when you want to update your every dependency to the latest version that satisfies your `'dep<majver'` constraints.

**Is there some kind of Alpine apk concept that fulfils the role of a "version lockfile"?**

> There is an obvious *Docker* solution: do the `apk add 'dep<majver'` step in a *separate* Dockerfile. Use that Dockerfile as a base image. Only rebuild that base Docker image when you're ready to bump your dependencies.

But I'm curious as to whether there's an *Alpine apk* solution, since this can be viewed as a *package-management* concern, not a *provisioning* concern.

Comment: I strongly concur with your goal (I've learnt the hard way that stuff *does* break if you don't pin versions).  Though what's wrong with the "explicitly specify exact versions" approach?

Comment: specifying exact versions is something I currently do _very manually_. I open a new container, dry-run the `dep<majver` resolution, and transcribe the latest results into my Dockerfile. it's error-prone. |||| it also means that my intention is no longer documented in the `apk add` command. people may think I have some strong reason to ask for a super-specific version, when really what I _mean_ is that I want a particular _major_ version, and want the outcome locked.

Comment: One other thing that occurs to me - if it **is** possible to generate a lockfile, presumably that would get generated *inside* the container, which would be a bit of a pain :/

Comment: Yup, that makes sense.

Comment: as you say: it's indeed a pain that the best way I would have of building lockfiles would be to do so _inside_ an alpine container. unavoidable, but automatable. I can fish it out with `docker copy`, put it into my source tree, and ensure that my Dockerfile copies that into the image.